# Need to know what USB cable to get for Arduino Nano-33-BLE-Sense

Tags: arduino-nano

I have recently purchased an Arduino Nano-33-BLE-Sense with Headers and wrongly assumed that it would come with a USB cable with it. I was searching the online store for the cable but the only cable on the store that I see is for Type A to Type B which in its description does not mention my board.

Does anyone have any experience with this board and know which cable I need? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you google `USB connector types` and compare pictures?

Comment: it is the most common USB cable. I am sure you have more then one at home. – Juraj Sep 26 at 9:02

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this board

[image: Nano-33-BLE-Sense]

Is connected to the PC with connector commonly named simply "Micro USB". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware) calls it "USB 2.0 Micro-B"
It's the same cable that all mobile phones used (before USB-C standard arrived). Check your phone charger.

[image: cable]